# read a text file and display data on canvas in j2me

Tags: java-me

I have searched but i am not getting , how to start, I want to read text file and shows all the  text data on canvas in j2me  using  eclipse.I have spent a lot of time for researching.

Comment: That are two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file with J2ME requires use of InputStreamReader. Presenting the data afterwards requires that you make some text-wrapping function. Noticing you only have 1 post here at SO I'm going to guess you're new at J2ME.

You might be better off using a HTML component, from e.g. LWUIT or J2MEPolish.

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/bbjidhgf.html

http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fire-j2me/

Answer (score 0):

To read file and display it on Canvas you should make three class containing the Midlet, the accesser class (to access files), and the class to display file list. You can use the code via this link, and it works:

http://belajarj2me.mwb.im/files/srcfilemanager.zip

If you want to test if the code works, you can download built application here:

http://belajarj2me.mwb.im/files/filemanager-jar.zip